# V-align top not working inside TD

Tags: html, asp.net, css, web-applications, user-interface

I have an asp.net gridview with the rendered HTML as below (only first column)

I want to align all three controls to top inside TD.

I tried by adding `vertical-align: top;` to TD but did not work as expected. It is showing some spaces on top.I also tried by adding DIV inside TD, placing control inside DIV and setting the CSS properties of DIV `vertical-align:top; display: table-row;`

It did not work too. 
This issue is in chrome and IE not FF

```
<td>      
        <input id="ctl00_PH_GridViewOrderDetails_ctl02_cbView" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PH$GridViewOrderDetails$ctl02$cbView"
            onclick="chkSelect(this.checked, this.id, 'chkView', 'cbView');">
        <span id="ctl00_PH_GridViewOrderDetails_ctl02_LineNo" style="font-size: 11px;">100 (10)</span>
        <img title="k@abc.com" src="Images/email.gif" >

</td>
```

Comment: you can use <td valign="top">

Comment: `vertical-align:top` ? not `valign="top"` ?

Comment: Why would you use the `valign` attribute now it is the 21st century?

Comment: You probably have some margin or padding lurking around. Use a DOM inspector to track it down (or provide a *complete* reduced test case, preferably duplicated at a live URL).

Comment: If ASP is relevant here, please explain how. Otherwise, present this as a CSS problem by presenting a self-contained minimal demo (HTML + CSS), and specify the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 2):

you need add vertical-align: top to all of items on your td not at td element:

```
td.yourIDorClass input, 
td.yourIDorClass img, 
td.yourIDorClass span {

    vertical-align: top;
}
```

or you can add attribute to all controls in code behind

```
youcontrolId.Attributes.Add("style", "vertical-align: top");
```

Answer (score 0):

make this in td give `valign="top"` or inside give `verticle-align:top;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skkwR/1/)**

```
  span, input{
    vertical-align:top; 
}
```